# Hide borders of hyperlinks in a limited region

Tags: hyperref, links, border

I know that to hide the borders around internal links, `hidelinks` option is always available:

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

But what if I need the ugly `hyperref` border for the Section 2 only but not for Sections 1 or 3?

```
\section{AAA}
Hyperlinks here should not have ugly borders
\section{BBB}
Hyperlinks here must have ugly borders
\section{CCC}
Hyperlinks here should not have ugly borders
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the borders on/odd using the key `pdfborder`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\nolinks}{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}}
\newcommand{\showlinks}{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{AAA}\label{AAA}%
\nolinks
Hyperlinks here should not have ugly borders \ref{BBB}.
\section{BBB}\label{BBB}%
\showlinks
Hyperlinks here must have ugly borders \ref{CCC}.
\section{CCC}\label{CCC}%
\nolinks
Hyperlinks here should not have ugly borders \ref{AAA}.

\end{document}
```